# Rails - make_resourceful with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am using the [make_resourceful](http://mr.hamptoncatlin.com/) plugin in my Rails app, and attempting to use nested resources.

My controller code looks like this:

```
class ClientRegionsController < ApplicationController
  make_resourceful do
    actions :all
    belongs_to :client

    response_for(:create) do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to client_client_regions_path }
    end

    response_for(:update) do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to client_client_regions_path }
    end
  end

  private

  def current_objects
    @current_objects ||= ClientRegion.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => "name")
  end
end
```

What I want to get on the index action is all the client_regions for a given client, i.e:

```
  client_1.client_regions
```

What I am actually getting is all the client regions in the system, i.e.:

```
ClientRegion.all
```

I've been scratching my head at this for a while, so I thought I'd ask here.

The weird thing is the other actions work as I expect, it is just the index action that is faulty.

Edit: my routes are defined as

```
map.resources :clients, :has_many => :client_regions
```

So the paths are

```
/clients/1/client_regions
/clients/1/client_regions/new
/clients/1/client_regions/20/edit
```

etc

Comment: What does your route look like?

I'm doing this using make_resourceful and it works fine for me.

If you can't figure it out, you can always override current_objects to set the collection manually.

Comment: I know I can easily work around it, but make_resourceful otherwise works so well I really want to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for posting your routes. This totally looks like it should work. What version of make_resourceful are you using? Updating to the latest code might fix it (that's what I'm using, and as I said, this works fine for us).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I fixed this myself.

I left some code out of the question to simplify it, but that was the source of the problem. (Have edited the question to put it back in)

The fix was to change the current_objects method to

```
def current_objects
    @current_objects ||= @client.client_regions.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => "name")
end
```

Quite obvious really in hindsight...